# Workflow for maintaining local Git repo shallow-cloned at latest release tag

Tags: git, package-management

I wanted to ask if there's a good workflow for this, or if I should just write a script. For some repositories, I'd like to:

- Shallow `git clone` the repo from the latest release tag
- Use a variation of `git pull` or `git fetch` to pull only the latest tag (provided there is one newer than the current checkout)
- Ideally, check out tags to their own branches
- Ideally, some way to prune the local repo to keep only the last N tags of history

Sometimes my package manager doesn't have some software, and I build it from source, and I'd like a nice way to keep minimal git repos on my disk that I can update and rebuild later as needed.

Currently I do something like this:

```
> git clone --depth 1 --branch=v4.0.3 git@github.com:mozilla/mozjpeg.git
Cloning into 'mozjpeg'...
[...]

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

$ cd mozjpeg
$ git switch -c v4.0.3
```

After that, if there's a new release, I'm not sure a good way to only get the next tags, or ideally only the latest tag.

I know I could do something like `git fetch --tags`, but that seems to fetch all tags from the past.

Mainly this is just for saving disk space, particularly for cloning repositories with long histories, but also considered writing automation to update my manually-built packages. (I realize I'm skirting the line of *"automation script"* and *"re-writing portage, but worse"*, but sometimes bad ideas are fun.)

---

P.S. I assume this is on-topic for StackOverflow based on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255430/2873090) but let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: You'll probably want to write a program for this (which, yes, does skirt those lines you mentioned...). I'll just put in one note here: if you have a *tag* `v4.0.3`, it's a bad idea to also create a *branch* named `v4.0.3`. It doesn't bother Git (these are in separate name spaces) but it gets extremely confusing for *humans*. As a general rule, the branch would be `release-4.0` or similar, with the tags going `v4.0.0`, `v4.0.1`, etc., assuming you count from zero (`v4.0.3` implies you do).

Comment: To find the set of tags in some remote Git repository (`origin` or raw URL), use `git ls-remote`, perhaps with `refs/tags` as a refspec limiter. This is less expensive than `git fetch --tags` since it doesn't have to bring over any commits as it's not creating the tags locally.